# Best way to format this data for exploratory factor analysis, using R?

Tags: r, data-transformation, factor-analysis

I originally asked this on StackOverflow, but it's more of a stats question than a coding question.

My question is about data formatting.  I have this dataset (well, this is just the first two of several hundred rows):

```
df <- structure(list(X.Case.ID. = 310:311, GENDER = c(1L, 1L), AGE = c(32L, 
45L), EMPLOYMENT = c(1L, 1L), EDUCATION = c(6L, 6L), FUNCTION = c(6L, 
6L), A = c(1L, 1L), SECTOR = 1:2, EMPLOYEES = c(567L, 500L), 
    STATE = c(35L, 10L), REGION = 3:2, REVENUE = 9:8, Q1 = c(2L, 
    2L), Q2 = 2:1, Q3 = 1:2, Q4 = c(1L, 3L), Q5 = 3:2, Q6_C1 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q6_C2 = 0:1, Q6_C3 = c(0L, 0L), Q6_C4 = 1:0, Q6_C5 = 0:1, 
    Q6_C6 = c(0L, 0L), Q6_C7 = c(0L, 0L), Q6_C8 = c(0L, 0L), 
    Q6_C9 = c(0L, 0L), O_Q6_C9 = c(NA, NA), Q7_C1 = 0:1, Q7_C2 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q7_C3 = c(0L, 0L), Q7_C4 = c(0L, 0L), Q7_C5 = 1:0, Q7_C6 = 0:1, 
    Q7_C7 = c(0L, 0L), Q7_C8 = c(0L, 0L), Q7_C9 = c(0L, 0L), 
    Q7_C10 = c(0L, 0L), O_Q7_C9 = c(NA, NA), Q8 = 4:3, Q9_C1 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q9_C2 = 0:1, Q9_C3 = c(0L, 0L), Q9_C4 = c(0L, 0L), Q9_C5 = c(1L, 
    1L), Q9_C6 = 0:1, Q9_C7 = c(0L, 0L), Q9_C8 = c(0L, 0L), Q9_C9 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q10 = c(3L, 1L), Q11_C1 = c(0L, 0L), Q11_C2 = 1:0, Q11_C3 = 0:1, 
    Q11_C4 = 0:1, Q11_C5 = 1:0, Q11_C6 = c(0L, 0L), Q11_C7 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q12 = c(34L, 15L), Q13 = c("99,994", "700"), Q14 = 1:2, 
    Q15 = 1:2, Q16_C1 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C2 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C3 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q16_C4 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C5 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C6 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q16_C7 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C8 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C9 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q16_C10 = c(0L, 0L), Q16_C11 = c(0L, 0L), O_Q16_C11 = c(NA, 
    NA), Q17_C1 = c(0L, 0L), Q17_C2 = c(0L, 0L), Q17_C3 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q17_C4 = c(0L, 0L), Q17_C5 = 1:0, Q17_C6 = 0:1, Q17_C7 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q17_C8 = 0:1, Q17_C9 = 0:1, Q17_C10 = 1:0, Q17_C11 = c(0L, 
    0L), Q17_C12 = c(0L, 0L), O_Q17_C11 = c(NA, NA), Q18 = c(5L, 
    3L), Q19_C1 = 0:1, Q19_C2 = 1:0, Q19_C3 = c(0L, 0L), Q19_C4 = 0:1, 
    Q19_C5 = c(0L, 0L), Q19_C6 = c(0L, 0L), Q19_C7 = c(0L, 0L
    ), Q19_C8 = c(0L, 0L), O_Q19_C7 = c(NA, NA), Q20_M1 = c(7L, 
    1L), Q20_M2 = 2:3, Q20_M3 = 3:4, Q20_M4 = 6:5, Q20_M5 = c(5L, 
    2L), Q20_M6 = c(4L, 7L), Q20_M7 = c(1L, 6L), YEARSATCOMPANY = c(7L, 
    10L), YEARSINBUS = c(12L, 10L), OFFICES = 3:2, SEGMENTS = c("Enterprise", 
    "Commercial"), DEDICATED_STAFF = c(">=20", "<20"), HOURS = c(">=10000", 
    "<1000"), VULNERABLE = c("Vulnerable", "Not Vulnerable"), 
    Hours.Adjusted = c("10000", "700"), Commerical.or.Enterprise = c("Enterprise", 
    "Commercial"), Q13.num = c(99994, 700), Segments = c(2, 1
    ), Dedicated.Staff = c(2, 1), Vulnerable = c(2, 1), Hours = c(4, 
    1)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I realize the column names and the values aren't clear but we have some questions, like the demographics, that each person has a single response to.

There are questions like Q1:
[image: Q1]

And then there are the questions like Q6, which has 9 parts to it (O_Q6_C9 and others like it are empty).  Here are the first 3 parts, for brevity.

[image: Q6]

Considering questions like Q6 are "long" questions in wide format, we essentially have one-to-one and one-to-many structure but formatted so it's all one-to-one. What's the best way to format this data for an exploratory factor analysis?  Leave it wide format or put it in long format which will result in the one-to-one variables to be duplicated?

I was wondering that for questions like Q6, all of the parts to it are around a common concept - would that pose problems?

I will be encoding all the data numerically and will not be using all of the questions.  However, I will be using a mix of the one-to-one and one-to-many questions.  Other than that mix of structure, there isn't anything complex like repeated measures or complex sampling.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most of the R packages for EFA use wide format, and I would use wide format for your data. The questions like Q6 might be best handled by a non-standard EFA, where you account for correlations between the pieces of Q6 separately from the other factors in the EFA. The psychometrics people would call Q6 a "testlet", and there are specific models for testlets. One thing to clarify is whether you want to treat the responses as continuous or as categorical/ordinal. Testlets more often involve categorical variables, but similar ideas can apply to continuous variables.

Comment: It's mostly categorical and not ordinal though a couple are ordinal, like Q1.  Thank you for introducing me to the concept of "testlets".  I will go do some reading up on it!  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer assuming that because you are using R, you will be using the `fa` function from the `psych` package to run the EFA. With this in mind, it is better to have your data in wide format for this purpose. The reason being is that the `fa` function will kick back the data with an error stating that the labels in the long data are not numeric. You could remove them, but then you have basically long column of variables in one, so the EFA will treat the data like it is just one variable.

The best way to do this is to simply run the data with just numeric items with column names, or as a correlation or covariance matrix instead (the latter is automatically converted to the former before the EFA is conducted).

Below are some examples using the `mtcars` data in R, where I run the EFA using a data frame, a tibble, a correlation matrix, and a covariance matrix:

```
#### Glimpse Data ####
library(tidyverse)
glimpse(mtcars)

#### Convert Data into Tibble, Cov/Cor Matrix, and Long Data ####
mt.tib <- mtcars %>% as_tibble()
mt.cov <- cov(mtcars)
mt.cor <- cor(mtcars)
mt.pivo <- mtcars %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "Measure",
               values_to = "Value")

#### DF, Tibble, and Cov ####
fa(mtcars,
   nfactors = 2,
   rotate = "oblimin") # data frame version

fa(mt.tib,
   nfactors = 2,
   rotate = "oblimin") # tibble version

fa(mt.cov,
   n.obs = nrow(mtcars), # have to supply n here
   nfactors = 2,
   rotate = "oblimin") # covariance matrix

fa(mt.cor,
   n.obs = nrow(mtcars), # have to supply n here
   nfactors = 2,
   rotate = "oblimin") # covariance matrix
```

All four of these have the same results:

```
Factor Analysis using method =  minres
Call: fa(r = mt.cor, nfactors = 2, n.obs = nrow(mtcars), rotate = "oblimin")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
       MR1   MR2   h2    u2 com
mpg  -0.61  0.54 0.85 0.147 2.0
cyl   0.71 -0.48 0.94 0.064 1.7
disp  0.58 -0.60 0.90 0.102 2.0
hp    0.89 -0.12 0.88 0.124 1.0
drat -0.17  0.78 0.71 0.292 1.1
wt    0.42 -0.70 0.82 0.179 1.6
qsec -0.92 -0.35 0.78 0.216 1.3
vs   -0.80  0.12 0.71 0.292 1.0
am    0.13  0.93 0.82 0.183 1.0
gear  0.22  0.93 0.80 0.200 1.1
carb  0.85  0.24 0.66 0.342 1.2

                       MR1  MR2
SS loadings           4.71 4.15
Proportion Var        0.43 0.38
Cumulative Var        0.43 0.81
Proportion Explained  0.53 0.47
Cumulative Proportion 0.53 1.00

 With factor correlations of 
      MR1   MR2
MR1  1.00 -0.28
MR2 -0.28  1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.4
Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.

df null model =  55  with the objective function =  15.4 with Chi Square =  408.01
df of  the model are 34  and the objective function was  2.76 

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.04 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.06 

The harmonic n.obs is  32 with the empirical chi square  6.87  with prob <  1 
The total n.obs was  32  with Likelihood Chi Square =  69.56  with prob <  0.00031 

Tucker Lewis Index of factoring reliability =  0.827
RMSEA index =  0.178  and the 90 % confidence intervals are  0.121 0.245
BIC =  -48.28
Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.99
Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                   MR1  MR2
Correlation of (regression) scores with factors   0.98 0.98
Multiple R square of scores with factors          0.97 0.96
Minimum correlation of possible factor scores     0.94 0.92
```

Running the EFA in long format reliably doesn't work because of the label vector created by the pivoted data:

```
#### Long Format ####
fa(mt.pivo,
   nfactors = 2,
   rotate = "oblimin")
```

Which gives us this (translation is that "x must be a numeric variable"):

```
Error in cor(r, use = use) : 'x'必需为数值
```

Simply removing it in this case doesn't work because it gives us nonsense output (due to it also being just one column of pivoted values:

```
fa(mt.pivo %>% select(-1),
   rotate = "oblimin")
```

As shown here:

```
Factor Analysis using method =  minres
Call: fa(r = mt.pivo %>% select(-1), rotate = "oblimin")
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
      MR1    h2 u2 com
Value   0 1e-30  1   1

               MR1
SS loadings      0
Proportion Var   0

Mean item complexity =  1
Test of the hypothesis that 1 factor is sufficient.

df null model =  0  with the objective function =  0 with Chi Square =  0
df of  the model are -1  and the objective function was  0 

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  NaN 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  NA 

The harmonic n.obs is  352 with the empirical chi square  0  with prob <  NA 
The total n.obs was  352  with Likelihood Chi Square =  0  with prob <  NA 

Tucker Lewis Index of factoring reliability =  NaN
Fit based upon off diagonal values = NaN
Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                  MR1
Correlation of (regression) scores with factors     0
Multiple R square of scores with factors            0
Minimum correlation of possible factor scores      -1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  This is good to know and I will take your advice, as well!

Comment: Great! If you feel either answer has provided a solution to your problem, feel free to hit the checkmark next to one of the answers here.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand ; this somewhat brushes over the issue that many of he data in the op are ordinal or dichotomous, where as you calculate pearson correlation

Comment: The key question here was regarding the data format, but yes OP would need to apply the proper arguments in R for that, I believe here using polychoric correlations using the `cor="poly"` argument.

Comment: Agreed. Which, and how, a specific analysis is carried out, using R in this case, can depend on the data format e.g. does the data need to be recorded as factors, integers, numeric etc. So data format is linked to analysis choice.